# how to use pagination in php?

Tags: php, wamp

i need to using a php pagination code for web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is also another:

- [Perfect PHP Pagination Tutorial](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/perfect-php-pagination)
- [Download Source](http://www.sitepoint.com/examples/pagination/paginated-demo.zip)

Answer (score 1):

There are a host of classes around  you can use for the pagination, here is one really nice:

- [Finally, the simple pagination class](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2007/07/28/finally-the-simple-pagination-class/)

See the **How to use:** section to know more :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You program it. The basic idea is you will be taking information from the `query string` and then using it to display certain data. Are you taking your data from a database? A couple of the things you will need to look at/think about are as follows:

```
$totalItems = 110;
$itemsPerPage = 5;
$pages = $totalItems / $itemsPerPage;
$currentPage = $_GET['page'];

for($i=0;$i < $pages;$i++){
   echo "<a href=\"?page=$i\">$i</a> ";
}  
//Your query would look something like this once it was done:
//SELECT `data` FROM `table` OFFSET $currentPage-1 * $itemsPerPage,$currentPage * $itemsPerPage
```

Then you will have to use these variables or something similar to make your database query fetch the correct data.